# php iconv keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, encode, iconv

Is there any decent way to iconv keys in a multidimensional array?

I need to json_encode one, but first it has to be in unicode, right? So, is there any hack or something? After some straightforward attemts (array_walk_recursive?) I've tried serializing the full array, then iconv, then unserializing - however all punctuation (i.e. brackets etc.) turned into a mess and unserializing just failed.

Comment: Can you paste your `array_walk_recursive` code and explain what didn't work for you?

Comment: Please post some relevant code to your question

Comment: i've already deleted it pretty long ago but it must have been smth like:

function test($value, &$key)
{
    unset($myarr[$key]);
    $myarr[iconv('windows-1251','utf-8', $key)] = $value;
}
array_walk_recursive($myarr, 'test');

or something like that, i tried it in a number of ways actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not achieve that with `array_walk_recursive()` in common case - since it will not work with those keys, [which values are arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

> Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function.

Instead of this you can write simple manual walk through:

```
function iconvKeys(array &$rgData, $sIn, $sOut)
{
   $rgData = array_combine(array_map(function($sKey) use ($sIn, $sOut)
   {
      return iconv($sIn, $sOut, $sKey);
   }, array_keys($rgData)), array_values($rgData));
   foreach($rgData as &$mValue)
   {
      if(is_array($mValue))
      {
         $mValue = iconvKeys($mValue, $sIn, $sOut);
      }
   }
   return $rgData;
}

$rgData = iconvKeys($rgData, 'UCS-2', 'UTF-8');//sample
```

-I suggest also to read [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) manual page to be aware about conversion modifiers.

Comment: suppose iconv($sIn, $sOut, $mKey)==$mKey
won't your function just lose some items by unsetting keys that haven't actually changed?

Comment: Hm.. that may be right. Thank you (I've not think about equality of `$sIn` and `$sOut` or that result could be equal, such as ASCII first 127 symbols and UTF-8)

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work:
`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 55396751 bytes)`

Comment: That's strange enough (was work for 1-byte to multibyte and now I've tryed UTF-8 to UCS-2 and that failed with error you've posted). I'll investigate, thanks for the challenge :p

Comment: thanks. and that's really weird - how can such recursion turn endless.

Comment: @user2831529 got that. Changing keys in referenced array caused trouble and unpredictable results, of cause. So safe way is to rebuild entire array itself.

Comment: Looks promising, but i have to use php 5.2 and looks like it doesn't allow inline function declaration, at least i'm getting  "unexpected T_FUNCTION" error. And if i declare the inner function explicitly, how can i pass $sIn and $sOut to it in array_map?

Comment: Use `create_function()` then

Comment: I ended up with 5.2-comapiable version

`function iconvKeys(array &$rgData, $sIn, $sOut)
{
 try /* 'cause array_combine rejects empty arrays */
 {
  $rgData = array_combine(array_map(  
  create_function('$sKey', 'return iconv("'.$sIn.'", "'.$sOut.'//IGNORE", $sKey);'), 
  array_keys($rgData)), array_values($rgData));
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
   /* empty array, skip key */
 }
 
 foreach($rgData as &$mValue)
 {
  if(is_array($mValue))
  {
   $mValue = iconvKeys($mValue, $sIn, $sOut);
  }
 }
 return $rgData;
}`